# Copy multiple files with the same file name from different locations into the same location

Tags: linux, file-copy

I want to copy multiple files with the same file name from different locations into the same location (by changing their names according to their original location).

For example, I want to copy,

```
/apple/test.txt
/banana/test.txt
/grape/test.txt
```

into

```
/fruits/apple_test.txt
/fruits/banana_test.txt
/fruits/grape_test.txt
```

Is there a method to do this in linux?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for fruit in apple banana grape; do
    cp "/${fruit}/test.txt" "/fruits/${fruit}_test.txt"
done
```

The loop executes three times; each time the variable `fruit` takes on one of the three values `apple`, `banana`, and `grape`.  For each fruit, it copies the original file to the destination file.